# Token is not updated and results into expired token (react-native-firebase/auth)

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, token, react-native-firebase

I have a problem in our expo app that if the token expires when the user is using our app, it returns an Error 401. I'm using FirebaseAuthGuard in our BE to authenticate the token. If I close and open the app, it does not return the 401 error.

How can I improve our code below to automatically detects a new token and assign it in our secureStore?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { clearUser, setUser } from "@/store/auth";
import auth, { FirebaseAuthTypes } from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { useAppDispatch } from "@/store";
import { clearSecureStore, saveSecureStore } from "../helpers/secureStore";

const useAuthentication = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  async function onAuthStateChanged(user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User) {
    const token = await user.getIdToken();
    await saveSecureStore("token", token);
    dispatch(
      setUser({
        email: user.email!,
        id: user.uid,
      }),
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        onAuthStateChanged(user);
      } else {
        dispatch(clearUser());
        await clearSecureStore("token");
      }
    });
    return subscriber;
  }, []);
};

export default useAuthentication;
```

I tried having a setInterval that will get another token in every 55 mins but sometimes it returns the outdate token since it's not sync in the refresh time of the firebase token.
Please help me since it is the only bug in our app.